# Upload multiple files from multiple file input in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-5

i try to make dynamic form that allow user to upload file in order that each image has video and they should upload and their path save to database but when i want to get file in my controller and store them in array i saw when i upload one or two files that work but when i try to upload more than 3 or 4 files my array becomes empty and i cannot solve it , please help me to complete my project thank a lot .

this is my  html form :

```
    <form action="admin/mediaUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="mediaUpload">
     <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tableAddRow">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>image</th>
                                <th>film</th>
                                <th style="width:10px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus addBtn" id="addBtn_0"></span></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr id="tr_0">
                                <td><input type="file" id="image_0" name="image-0" class="form-control"/></td>
                                <td><input type="file" id="video_0" name="video-0" class="form-control" /></td>
                                <td style="background-color: white;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus addBtnRemove" style="margin-top: 9px;" id="addBtnRemove_0"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="mediaSubmit" value="بارگذاری" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right; width: 40%"/><br/><br/>
                    </form>
```

and this is my controller :

```
public function mediaUpload(uploadRequest $uploadRequest)
{
    $data = $uploadRequest->all();
    $numberId = $uploadRequest['numberId'];
    $rowCount = $uploadRequest['rowCount'];

    $imageArray = [];
    $videoArray = [];

    for($i = 0 ; $i<$rowCount - 1 ;$i++)
    {
        $imageArray[$i] = Input::file('image-'.$i);
    }

    for($i = 0 ; $i<$rowCount - 1 ;$i++)
    {
        $videoArray[$i] = Input::file('video-'.$i);
    }

    var_dump($imageArray);
    var_dump($videoArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array inside the inputs:

```
<tr id="tr_0">
    <td><input type="file" id="image_0" name="image[]" class="form-control"/></td>
    <td><input type="file" id="video_0" name="video[]" class="form-control" /></td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr_1">
    <td><input type="file" id="image_1" name="image[]" class="form-control"/></td>
    <td><input type="file" id="video_1" name="video[]" class="form-control" /></td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr_2">
    <td><input type="file" id="image_2" name="image[]" class="form-control"/></td>
    <td><input type="file" id="video_2" name="video[]" class="form-control" /></td>
</tr>
```

And then just loop the request property:

```
if (Input::hasFile('video')) {
    foreach (Input::file('video') as $video) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

The same for `image`

Comment: i try your solution but if i add 5 <tr> it is not work , i wonder that it detect 3 video or image but not working for 4 5 or 6 and so on

Comment: Try to increase `upload_max_filesize` then http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php, also check if your front-end works correctly.

Comment: i increase upload_max_filesize  to 500M but not working yet :(